# HBase Scan based on specific HFile(s) as roots

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase, hfile

Is there any Scan/Filter API with the following behavior?

Given time range, I would like the scanner to include data from HFiles out of range, for row keys included in the HFiles which are in range.
The idea is to scan in-memory indexes of all HFiles, but get data from disk only for rowkeys from HFiles that are in range.

For example, if `HFile1` is in range and `HFile2` is out of range, and `rowkey1` has any data in `HFile1`, I would like to get all columns of `rowkey1` from `HFile2` as well, as if it were in range.
On the other hand, if `rowkey2` is included in `HFile2` but not in `HFile1`, the index scanner should just skip to the next row key.

The use case is to load **entire rows** that were modified (even on just one column) during the last X hours, avoiding full scan or any disk scan of redundant data.
This is going to be integrated into Spark/MR applications, probably based on TableSnapshotInputFormat, so I guess I could ship some custom code for HRegion, HStore, or whatever, if it comes to this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If this is the use case,

> The use case is to load entire rows that were modified (even on just
>   one column) during the last X hours, avoiding full scan or any disk
>   scan of redundant data

Why the Scan with timestamp range will not work? The HBase JAVA API `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setTimeRange(long, long)` takes a time-range as input & it fetches rows which were modified in this time-range only.

If you want it to be more flexible, then apply a `KeyOnlyFilter()` and get all the rowkeys. Later you can do a batch `Get` based on the row count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `setTimeRange` will not work because it only fetches the modified column, and I need the **entire** row. We already do something similar to what you suggested with batch `Get`, and this is exactly the process I try to optimize :)